# Is Inverse-Wishart a conjugate prior for Wishart likelihood?

Tags: bayesian, posterior, conjugate-prior, wishart-distribution, inverse-wishart

Suppose I have a noisy observation $Z$ of a covariance matrix $F$, given a prior on $F: p(F)$, I would like to find the posterior of $p(F|Z)$, does the following specification forms conjugacy?:

$$ F \sim IW(v, F_0)$$
$$Z|F \sim W(v_k , \frac{F}{v_k})$$
$IW$ denotes Inverse-Wishart, $W$ denotes Wishart. $Z$ is a noisy observation of $F$ since $E[Z|F] = v_k \frac{F}{v_k} = F$.

My derivation shows that they are conjugate but I cannot find anything similar online, so my derivations should be incorrect. Where went wrong?:

$$p(F|Z) \propto p(F) p(Z|F) $$
$$\propto |F|^{-\frac{v + p +1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2} Tr(F_0 F^{-1})} |F|^{-\frac{d}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2} Tr(v_k F^{-1} Z)}$$
$$=|F|^{-\frac{v + p +1}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2} Tr(F_0 F^{-1})} |F|^{-\frac{v_k}{2}}e^{-\frac{1}{2} Tr(v_k  Z F^{-1})} \text{ (by $Tr(AB) = Tr(BA)$)}$$
$$=|F|^{-\frac{v+p+1+v_k}{2}} e^{-\frac{1}{2}Tr((F_0 + v_k Z)F^{-1})}$$
$$\sim IW(v+v_k, F_0 + v_k Z)$$

Does the Bayes' Theorem apply to two random matrices?

Answer (score 6):

This is actually quite a well-known result in Bayesian statistics (see e.g., [Evans 1965](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2984196), [Chen 1979](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2985038), [Dickey, Lindley and Press 1985](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/03610928508828960) and [Leonard and Hsu 1992](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2242363)).  In most of the literature on Bayesian analysis of this problem it is typical for the analysis to be framed in terms of the [precision matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_(statistics)) $\mathbf{P} = \mathbf{F}^{-1}$ rather than the variance matrix $\mathbf{F}$, so the usual way your result would be framed is entirely in terms of the Wishart distribution:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{P} &\sim \text{Wishart}(\text{df} = v, \text{Precision} = \mathbf{P}_0), \\[12pt]
\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{P} &\sim \text{Wishart}(\text{df} = v_k, \text{Precision} = v_k \mathbf{P}). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

This is equivalent to your formulation:

$$\begin{align}
\mathbf{F} &\sim \text{InvWishart}(\text{df} = v, \text{Variance} = \mathbf{F}_0), \\[6pt]
\mathbf{Z}|\mathbf{F} &\sim \text{Wishart} \bigg( \text{df} = v_k, \text{Variance} = \frac{\mathbf{F}}{v_k} \bigg). \\[6pt]
\end{align}$$

You appear to have made some minor errors in your algebra, but those do not affect your ultimate result, which is correct.  From the [Wishart distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wishart_distribution) you have likelihood function:

$$L_\mathbf{z}(\mathbf{F}) \propto |\mathbf{F}|^{-v_k/2} \exp \bigg( -\frac{1}{2} \text{tr}(v_k \mathbf{F}^{-1} \mathbf{z}) \bigg).$$

Taking the prior density $\pi$ from the [inverse-Wishart distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse-Wishart_distribution) gives the form:

$$\pi(\mathbf{F}) \propto |\mathbf{F}|^{-(v+p+1)/2} \exp \bigg( -\frac{1}{2} \cdot  \text{tr}(\mathbf{F}_0 \mathbf{F}^{-1}) \bigg),$$

which gives the posterior form:

$$\begin{align}
\pi(\mathbf{F} | \mathbf{z})
&\propto |\mathbf{F}|^{-(v+v_k+p+1)/2} \exp \bigg(  -\frac{1}{2} \cdot  \text{tr}(\mathbf{F}_0 \mathbf{F}^{-1}) -\frac{1}{2} \text{tr}(v_k \mathbf{F}^{-1} \mathbf{z})\bigg) \\[6pt]
&= |\mathbf{F}|^{-(v+v_k+p+1)/2} \exp \bigg( -\frac{1}{2} \bigg[ \text{tr}(\mathbf{F}_0 \mathbf{F}^{-1}) + \text{tr}(v_k \mathbf{F}^{-1} \mathbf{z}) + \bigg] \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= |\mathbf{F}|^{-(v+v_k+p+1)/2} \exp \bigg( -\frac{1}{2} \bigg[ \text{tr}(\mathbf{F}_0 \mathbf{F}^{-1}) + \text{tr}(v_k \mathbf{z} \mathbf{F}^{-1}) \bigg] \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= |\mathbf{F}|^{-(v+v_k+p+1)/2} \exp \bigg( -\frac{1}{2} \bigg[ \text{tr}(\mathbf{F}_0 \mathbf{F}^{-1} + v_k \mathbf{z} \mathbf{F}^{-1}) \bigg] \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= |\mathbf{F}|^{-(v+v_k+p+1)/2} \exp \bigg( -\frac{1}{2} \bigg[ \text{tr}((\mathbf{F}_0 + v_k \mathbf{z}) \mathbf{F}^{-1}) \bigg] \bigg) \\[6pt]
&= |\mathbf{F}|^{-(v+v_k+p+1)/2} \exp \bigg( -\frac{1}{2} \bigg[ \text{tr}( (\mathbf{F}_0 + v_k \mathbf{z}) \mathbf{F}^{-1}) \bigg] \bigg) \\[12pt]
&\propto \text{InvWishart}(\mathbf{F} | v+v_k, \mathbf{F}_0 + v_k \mathbf{z}). \\[14pt]
\end{align}$$